# Strange script font appearing in Google search results and Firebug

Tags: google, firefox

The weirdest thing has just occurred. I did a google search and once the page had rendered I could see double f's had been replaced with a strange script font. Even weirder, once I chose to have a look using Firebug, the strange script font appeared there also. Why is this?

I've attached a picture of what I saw.[image]

P.S. The Search was for "[wget facebook](http://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&safe=off&client=firefox-a&hs=SUV&rls=org.mozilla%3Aen-US%3Aofficial&q=wget+facebook&aq=f&aqi=g1&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=)" and I'm using Firefox 3.6 on Mac OS X 10.5

Answer (score 3):

The character is "ﬃ": [`Unicode Character 'LATIN SMALL LIGATURE FFI' (U+FB03)`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fb03/index.htm)

Why your computer is choosing a script font to handle it, I'd check your localization and internationalization settings for your computer.

Answer (score 0):

The font is different here, too.
It's not like yours but it's notably different. Seems the problem isn't in your computer.

Answer (score 0):

I think they are updating on this site.. so that's why it turns out like that..like this one
http://bit.ly/strang_e